# Power shell copy item search on selected files recursively and copy only file to destination folder

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I want to fetch a specific file recursively which may exists in sub-folders and copy it to destination folder.

I tried executing below command:

Get-ChildItem "D:\Source Directory" | Copy-Item -Destination "D:\Target Directory" -Recurse -filter file.doc

The command copied more files then the one fetched.

Any better solution?

Comment: Your -Flter and -Recurse both need to be on the Get-ChildItem  command not the Copy-Item command. You'll also run into a problem trying to copy multiple files of the same name to a single directory. Some rethinking is in order.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Source Directory" -Recurse -Filter "file.doc" -File |  Copy-Item -Destination "D:\Target Directory" is working

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Source Directory" -Recurse -Filter "file.doc" -File | Copy-Item -Destination "D:\Target Directory"